# Tutorial on classifying handwritten digits has wrong/missing attribute

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am following the tutorial for [Classifying Handwritten Digits with TF.Learn](https://github.com/random-forests/tutorials/blob/master/ep7.ipynb)

The last part of the tutorial is where I have a problem. It seems like `classifier.weights_` doesn't exist anymore.

This is the error message: `AttributeError: 'LinearClassifier' object has no attribute 'weights_'`

```
weights = classifier.weights_
f, axes = plt.subplots(2, 5, figsize=(10,4))
axes = axes.reshape(-1)
for i in range(len(axes)):
    a = axes[i]
    a.imshow(weights.T[i].reshape(28, 28), cmap=plt.cm.seismic)
    a.set_title(i)
    a.set_xticks(()) # ticks be gone
    a.set_yticks(())
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TensorFlow has been changing pretty fast in the past couple of years, and anything using a version prior to 1.0 is likely to be out of date.  The `LinearClassifier.weights_` attribute has been removed and there doesn't seem to be an exact match for it.  What you can do is ask for the list of variables and then pass the variable you want to `weights`.  To do this, use

```
for var in classifier.get_variable_names():
    print("var:", var, "=", classifier.get_variable_value(var))
```

In my case this gives me three weight variables named "linear//weight", "linear//weight/d/linear//weight/part_0/Ftrl", and "linear//weight/d/linear//weight/part_0/Ftrl_1", along with some other stuff.  These tensors are quite big, so their values are shown only in abbreviated form.  Then you can pass one of them to `weights`:

```
weights = classifier.get_variable_value("linear//weight/d/linear//weight/part_0/Ftrl_1")
```

and you should see something like the image in the tutorial.  All three of them are similar but they're not the same, so possibly LinearClassifier is doing something more complex than it used to.